# asp.net email SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email

I have a asp.net page that send an email to me.

`SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");` work fine.

What does it mean ? when I change it to `SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1";`, it fails.

`When I say SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "")`, what I am exactly setting as my SMTP server ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");
```

does nothing.

`SmtpServer` property is of type String so you are basically calling string.Insert(int, string) which does not affect the string that you are calling insert on but returns a new instance of string with the with what you are trying to insert.

```
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "google.com";
SmtpMail.SmtpServer =  SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "mail."); 
// now  SmtpMail.SmtpServer will be "mail.google.com"
```

Comment: so, how is the page working ? I mean what is my smtp server ?

SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");
        SmtpMail.Send(message);

Comment: Do you have smtp server defined in your web.config? when you set the SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1", it will override the one from web.config but when you don't and just do `SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");` which does nothing and leaves SmtpServer with blank string, it will take the one that's defined in web.config.

Comment: that is another problem ...

<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\domains\xxxx\wwwroot\Test\"/>
     </smtp>
  </mailSettings>

I am writing to the disk, but somehow the email comes to me and is not written to the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, SmtpServer is obsolete.  You should use `SmtpClient` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
//...
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
// setup mail properties...

client.Send(message);
```